# QGIS - Moving Line Features Large Distances

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, features, move

I have two layers on my map: reserve boundaries (polygons) and reserve trails (lines). I am using WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) and projected my trails from WGS 84 / UTM Zone 17N (EPSG:32617) to match my polygon and project CRS.

However, my trails layer is not aligned with my reserve boundaries layer and the distance between them is too great to be moved manually using the editor tools. Following up online I found the "Move Features" plugin, but I cannot get it to perform the transformations. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If it matters the reserve trails layer was originally a MapInfo (.TAB) file that I converted to .SHP.

Comment: You can shift layer with processing tool by x and y coordinate.

Comment: did you just set the CRS instead of exporting the data with a new CRS?

Comment: If your data is not confidential I'd suggest that posting links to the polygon layer and the line layer might be helpful.